# Dynamically convert Java thread into openCL kernel

Tags: java, opencl

Is there any API or way to convert Java Thread into Open Cl Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

APARAPI

https://code.google.com/p/aparapi/

does exactly that - with some limitation - as not any java code can be translated.